# preencher array para gerar json javascript

Tags: array

Preciso preencher um vetor multdimensional para transformar em json, nao estou conseguindo acho que sempre o ultimo valor sobreescreve o anterior

```
array_fotos = { "id": 1, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() }; 
array_fotos = { "id": 2, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() };
```

.....
como faria isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está sobrepondo os dados pois está jogando na mesma posição da variável
Tente isso:

```
var array_fotos = new Array();
array_fotos[0] = { "id": 1, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() }; 

array_fotos[1] = { "id": 1, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() };
```

ou utilizado o método push:

```
var array_fotos = new Array();
    array_fotos.push({ "id": 1, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() });
```

Answer (score 1):

A maneira certa de fazer isso é utilizando o método `push`:

```
var array_fotos = [];

array_fotos.push({ "id": 1, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() }); 
array_fotos.push({ "id": 2, "foto": imgName, "tamanho": $(".tamanho_fotos").val(), "quantidade": $("[name='quantidade']").val() });
```