# Vetor ou Array multidimensional no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá mestres do JavaScript, estou estudando vetores multidimensionais, tenho o seguinte código, o arquivo .js:

```
var funcionarios = [[]], indiceLinha, indiceColuna;
```

para o arquivo index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Aprendendo Algoritmos com JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/aplicativo_021.js"></script>   
    <script>        
        for (indiceLinha = 0; indiceLinha < 2; indiceLinha++)
        {
            funcionarios[indiceLinha] = (prompt("Digite o Nome do Funcionário:"));
            for (indiceColuna = 0; indiceColuna < 2; indiceColuna++)
            {                   
                funcionarios[indiceColuna] = (prompt("Digite o Cargo do Funcionário:"));
                funcionarios[indiceLinha] = (prompt("Digite o Nome do Funcionário:"));
            }
        }       

        for (indiceLinha = 0; indiceLinha < 2; indiceLinha++)       
        {
            for (indiceColuna = 0; indiceColuna < 2; indiceColuna++)
            {           
                document.write("Nome do Funcionário " + funcionarios[indiceLinha] + "\n");
                document.write("<br>");
                document.write("Cargo do Funcionário " + funcionarios[indiceColuna] + "\n");
                document.write("<br>");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Não consigo ver onde estou errando. Quem puder ajudar, fico no aguardo.

Comment: Vou responder da mesma forma que respondi nos comentários de uma pergunta há uns 40 minutos atrás, pesquise sobre matrizes com javascript, e então utilize por exemplo, o modelo `matriz[i][j] = valor`. Se ainda assim tiver dúvidas, elas estarão melhor elaboradas. qualquer coisa, edita a pergunta

Comment: Caro Murilo, muito obrigado por sua resposta, não ajudou muito, pois quando recorro ao forum, é porque já pesquisei sobre o assunto e não consegui achar o que queria., mesmo assim muito grato pelo seu precioso tempo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [preencher array para gerar json javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189016/preencher-array-para-gerar-json-javascript)